# tkinter call two functions

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to make it so that a Tkinter button calls two function?

some thing like this maybe?:

```
from Tkinter import *

admin = Tk()
def o():
    print '1'

def t():
    print '2'
button = Button(admin, text='Press', command=o, command=t)
button.pack()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make a new function that calls both:

```
def o_and_t():
    o()
    t()
button = Button(admin, text='Press', command=o_and_t)
```

Alternatively, you can use this fun little function:

```
def sequence(*functions):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        return_value = None
        for function in functions:
            return_value = function(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_value
    return func
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
button = Button(admin, text='Press', command=sequence(o, t))
```

Answer (score 19):

you can use the sample way with lambda like this:

```
button = Button(text="press", command=lambda:[function1(), function2()])
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're trying for doesn't exist unfortunately. What you'd need to do is make a wrapper function that runs both of your functions. A lazy solution would be something like:

```
def multifunction(*args):
    for function in args:
        function(s)

cb = lambda: multifunction(o, t)
button = Button(admin, text='Press', command=cb)
```

Answer (score -3):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but whenever I needed a button to operate multiple functions, I would establish the button once:

```
button = Button(admin, text='Press', command=o)
```

And then add  another function using the `.configure()`:

```
button.configure(command=t)
```

Added to your script, it would look like this

```
from Tkinter import *

admin = Tk()
def o():
    print '1'

def t():
    print '2'

button = Button(admin, text='Press', command=o)
button.configure(command=t)
button.pack()
```

This could run multiple functions, well as a function and a `admin.destroy` or any other command without using a global variable or having to redefine anything

Comment: You're mistaken — only the last `command=` function configured (`t` in this case) will be executed.