# Entry widget won't clear upon function

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to get the Entry to widget to clear (clearTextBox()) but also run newQuote(). since I added the second bind it won't clear out. Any ideas?

```
from random import *
from tkinter import *

def clearTextBox(event):
    textBox.delete(0, END)
    textBox.insert(0, "")

def newQuote(event):
    rightLabel.config(text=quotes[randint(0,10)])

textBox = Entry(leftFrame, width=60)
textBox.pack(ipady=10, side=LEFT)
textBox.bind("<Return>", clearTextBox)
textBox.bind("<Return>", newQuote)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call to `bind` overwrites the first.

To fix this, you can add the keyword argument `add="+"`, to call both functions:

```
textBox.bind("<Return>", newQuote, add="+")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, worked perfectly! I'll press the tick in 8 minutes, you were just too fast

Comment: I'd also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839549/7032856) for calling of multiple functions using only one callback function.